# How to set force reset password when login with temporary password in active directory from c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have the following code to reset the password for the user in active directory and the code is working fine. Somehow I would like to force the user to reset their password when they first login into the computer with the temporary password. I tried to use both `uEntry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;` and `uEntry.Properties["PasswordExpired"].Value = 1`, it's doesn't work. Anyone know how can I make it happen?

```
DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn, "abc", "abc123");
uEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
uEntry.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
uEntry.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points to note:

- Call `uEntry.CommitChanges();` to commit the change after setting pwdLastSet
- The `userDn` in `new DirectoryEntry(userDn, "abc", "abc123");` should be an LDAP path instead of really a DN. For example:

  `LDAP://example.com/CN=user,DC=example,DC=com` instead of `CN=user,DC=example,DC=com`
- Make sure the "password never expire" flag is not set for user
  To clear this, clear the DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD (0x10000) bit in userAccountControl attribute.

Comment: the userDn is start with LDAP, and I have also tried to put the line uEntry.CommitChanges(); before the uEntry.Close();.But yet, it's still not working

Comment: Did you check also the password never expire option? If this is set, setting pwdLastSet to 0 has no effect. I tried after clearing the option, the code can force user to change password on next logon.

Comment: "password never expire" unchecked. But yet still it will not force the user to reset the password when it's login with the temporary password